# need click twice after hide a shown bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$('#popoverlink').popover();

$("#popoverhide").click(function() {
   $("#popoverlink").popover("hide"); 
});
```

```css
#popoverlink {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" id="popoverlink" class="btn" rel="popover" title="Some title">Popover</a>
<a href="#" id="popoverhide" class="btn" rel="popover" title="Some title">hide</a>
```

Same with the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npq3A/98/). Sorry the previous link was wrong. This one is correct.

After I hide the shown popover, I need to click the popover trigger twice to show it again.

Is this a bug? Is there anything can avoid this?

**UPDATE**
I means I used another button to hide a popover by

```
$("#popoverTrigger").popover("hide");
```

Than I need to click the "#popoverTrigger" twice to show it.

**STUPID SOLUTION**

```
$("popoverhide").click(function() {
    var f = false;
    if($("popoverlink").next('div.popover:visible')) {
        f = true;
        $("popoverlink").popover("hide");
    }
    if(f) {
        $("popoverlink").click();
    }
})
```

Is there another good idea?

Comment: Doesn't seem like that on my computer..

Comment: yes ,Its working well for me too

Comment: `Popever` on its own works fine. Try this, click on popover and activate the tooltip thing, then hide it using hide button, and then try to click on popover. It won't show up at the first click, but on the second. Seems like a bug.

Comment: You'll only notice the bug if you're using v3.3.5 of bootstrap. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I experienced this bug in 3.3.6

Comment: The same issue is affecting tooltips, and the solutions are the same.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Still not fixed in 3.3.6 but I found a proposed solution here:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16732

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/17702/files#diff-f3e99e0bb007ace7a370f0492b9cb5abR340

I've applied it in the hidden event:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.popover', function (e) {
    $(e.target).data("bs.popover").inState.click = false;
});
```

This works for me. To be exactly the same as the proposed fix it would be:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.popover', function (e) {
    $(e.target).data("bs.popover").inState = { click: false, hover: false, focus: false }
});
```

Note: I use delegated popovers which is why i'm using the $('body') reference.

For **Bootstrap 4** use `_activeTrigger` instead of `inState`:

```
$(e.target).data("bs.popover")._activeTrigger.click = false
```

Comment: WOW. This is really work!
But I had not used this for a while. SAD

Comment: Bug persists in 3.3.7 and looks like they are holding off until v4. This solution still works 

Comment: Until 4.0.0-alpha.5, the bug persists. This solution becomes
```$(e.target).data("bs.popover")._activeTrigger.click = false```

Comment: Unbeleavable. And to think that I wasted five hours looking at my code thinking it was my fault

Comment: @TingYiShih thanks a lot!! I just googled how I can fix it for Bootstrap 4. And your solution works great!

Comment: @jules what about bootstrap 5, i mean any solution for that
please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869655/close-button-in-bootstrap-5-popover-and-close-popover-on-body-click

Answer (score 6):

I recently came across this bug and this is how I fixed it:

```
$('.myPopoverClass')
    .popover({
        trigger: 'manual', /* <- important, instantiates popover */
        container: 'body', /* optional */
        animation: false
    })
    .click(function(e) {
        $('.popover').not(this).hide(); /* optional, hide other popovers */
        $(this).popover('show'); /* show popover now it's setup */
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Was getting an issue that popover would trigger when I didn't want it to. Realised after your comment that it was set to trigger: 'focus' and so whenever the button was focused it would trigger while I wanted it triggered manually.

Comment: what about bootstrap 5 any of given solution not working

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in v3.3.5:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16732

Just use 3.3.4 for now until it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

make sure popover will be initialized only once.if it will be initialized more than
one time across different files you may get this problem.

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    placement : 'bottom'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('toggle');
```

Instead of:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a popup that fades out after 3 secs and needed double click to reopen it. Followed Darren's solution and it worked.

```
$(function () {

    $('#popLinks').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        animation: true
    });

    $('#popLinks').click(function () {
        $(this).popover('show');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.popover').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 3000);
        e.preventDefault();
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Darren's answer above. Sorry Darren, I still can't comment on other's post. 
One slight change though. I changed 'show' to 'toggle' to be able to toggle the popup box.

From:

```
$(this).popover('show');
```

To

```
$(this).popover('toggle');
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using the lines of code below:

Explanation: hide the shown popover before showing the new one using *show.bs.popover* event

Important! do not use $('.popover').hide(); it will prevent the popover to be shown until you click twice, but use $('element').popover('hide') instead

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
                                    try {
                                        $('element').popover('hide');
                                    } catch (ex) {
                                        console.log(ex);
                                    }
                                });
// then use $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); to show your popover
```

It works also in case of multiple popover.