# Why are data-show and data-toggle equal when working with Bootstrap popovers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**`data-show` is behaving as `data-toggle`.**

I have `data-show="popover"` attribute on a DOM element, and I'm using a script that calls `popoverElement.popover('hide');` when clicking a button.

After this custom script has closed the popover, when I try to open it again by clicking the `[data-show]` element, two clicks are needed to open the popover. Nothing happens on the first click.

I know that this problem can be solved with JavaScript, however I'd like to know if there's a simpler solution.

Comment: Could you add some code here or to jsfiddle for us that recreates your issue. Easier to help you that way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a bug in Bootstrap 3, only fixed in v4. A fix is available on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34320956/2064544)