# Bootstrap popover takes two clicks to open the popover after the first popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have used bootstrap popover. Here my popover works well on the first click. After closing the popover, if i open the popover again, its not opening on first click. Instead it takes two click. **Note:** In the fiddle everything is working fine. But, in my file it takes two click to open the popover

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<h1><span data-toggle="popover" data-content="<a href='#' data-toggle='popover' onclick='$(&quot;.popover-close&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);return false;' class='close'>&times;</a><p><b>Enjoy Unfair Advantage Over Your Competitors</b></p><ol class='mrgn-lft-15'><li><p><b>Priority placement of Corporate Members' companies</b> in search results and product category pages significantly improves their visibility and let buyers find and contact Corporate Members when they search or browse [site name] for what Corporate Members sell. The improved visibility helps Corporate Members win <b>more inquiries</b> than their lower ranking competitors i.e. Diamond, Pro, and Basic Members.</p></li><li><p><b>Priority placement of Corporate Members’ quotations</b> sent to buyers ensures their quotations are seen at the top of all quotations received by buyers. This added visibility significantly improves the chances of Corporate Members’ quotations being viewed and responded to by buyers.</p></li></ol>"
    data-html="true" data-placement="right" data-container="body" class="label label-default popover-close">Details</span></h1>
```

Comment: `data-content="<div class='alert-dismissable'>` ! look twice

Comment: Hi all i have edited my question, Please help me.

Comment: In this snippet, it works fine, open with single click after close.

Comment: @Pedram - Yep, here its working fine. But the same code not working in my page. can you see the below URL in mobile view. I have used popover in corporate's first details badge. https://html.paperindex.com/boost-your-sales.html

Comment: Where I should click to see popover?

Comment: @Pedram - Thank you :) - Finally i added the below code to fix the issue. $('body').on('hidden.bs.popover', function (e) {
            $(e.target).data("bs.popover").inState.click = false;
        });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581987/need-click-twice-after-hide-a-shown-bootstrap-popover

Comment: where we need to add this lines @Alukkupaiyan