# Need click twice after hide a tooltip in ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

There is

- Input - show tooltip with text "A" or "B" over this input,
- Button A - open tooltip "A"
- Button B - open tooltip "B"

Scenario:

1. Click Button A - tooltip "A" opened,
2. Click Button B - I expect tooltip "A" closed and tooltip "B" opened. But only tooltip "A" closed and **tooltip "B" not opened**.
3. Click again Button B - now tooltip "B" opened.

Example:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input ngbTooltip="" triggers="manual" #tooltip="ngbTooltip" />
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" (click)="openA()">
  Click me to open tooltip "A"
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" (click)="openB()">
  Click me to open tooltip "B"
</button>
```

```
  @ViewChild('tooltip') tooltip: NgbTooltip

  openA() {
    this.tooltip.close()
    this.tooltip.ngbTooltip = "A"
    this.tooltip.open()
  }

  openB() {
    this.tooltip.close()
    this.tooltip.ngbTooltip = "B"
    this.tooltip.open()
  }
```

Online example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ootwp5-rszbjm?file=src/app/tooltip-triggers.html) (based on [official example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples#triggers)).

I found possible workaround for this bug in Bootstrap tooltip: [need click twice after hide a shown bootstrap popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581987/need-click-twice-after-hide-a-shown-bootstrap-popover/34320956#34320956). But I don't know how to use it this with Angular library ng-bootstrap (`ngbTooltip`):

Comment: Did you try passing the `ngbTooltip` reference to a generic function as demonstrated [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pzbqhu--run?file=src/app/tooltip-tplwithcontext.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented workaround. New filed (boolean flag) to decide if tooltip should be opened and use it in event `hidden` to try open again. It works, but I think it's not the best solution.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input ngbTooltip="" triggers="manual" #tooltip="ngbTooltip" 
  (hidden)="openTooltipIfShouldOpenWhenHidden()" />
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" (click)="openA()">
  Click me to open tooltip "A"
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" (click)="openB()">
  Click me to open tooltip "B"
</button>
```

```
  @ViewChild('tooltip') tooltip: NgbTooltip

  tooltipShouldOpen = false

  openA() {
    this.tooltip.close()
    this.tooltip.ngbTooltip = "A"
    this.tooltipShouldOpen = true
    this.tooltip.open()
  }

  openB() {
    this.tooltip.close()
    this.tooltip.ngbTooltip = "B"
    this.tooltipShouldOpen = true
    this.tooltip.open()
  }

  openTooltipIfShouldOpenWhenHidden() {
    if (this.tooltipShouldOpen) {
      this.tooltipShouldOpen = false
      this.tooltip.open()
    }
  }
```

Online example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ootwp5-rlreat?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-triggers.ts)