# Close button in bootstrap 5 popover and close popover on body click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I need to close popover on button click inside `data-bs-content` in bootstrap 5 popovers also there is no function on popover close on body click.

following is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        // popover
        var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
        var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
          return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
        })
        


      });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn  btn-primary ripple-effect m-4" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-content="<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='d-flex justify-content-end close-popover' aria-label='Close'><div class='icon icon-16 icon-lg-16 mb-2'>X</div></a><div  class='sec-paragraph'><div class='p4'><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur apising elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</p></div> </div>">Popover(White) left with close btn</a>
```

JS

```
    return function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // popover
    var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
    var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
      return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
    })
  });
}
```

HTMl

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn  btn-default ripple-effect m-4" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-content="<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='d-flex justify-content-end close-popover' aria-label='Close'><div class='icon icon-16 icon-lg-16 mb-2'><img src='resources/img/svg-icons/icon-close-grey.svg' alt='popover close icon'></div></a><div  class='sec-paragraph'><div class='p4'><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur apising elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</p></div> </div>">Popover(White) left with close btn</a>
```

Also if we use hide function as per their doc then we cant reopen popover, check below code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        // popover
        var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
        var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
          return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
        })
        
        
        $(document).on("click", ".popover .close-popover" , function(){
          $(this).closest(".popover").hide();
      });


      });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn  btn-primary ripple-effect m-4" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-content="<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='d-flex justify-content-end close-popover' aria-label='Close'><div class='icon icon-16 icon-lg-16 mb-2'>X</div></a><div  class='sec-paragraph'><div class='p4'><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur apising elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</p></div> </div>">Popover(White) left with close btn</a>
```

Comment: What's your expected behavior ? What's the actual one that you get ?

Comment: have you tried answers from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17654845/19330634) ?

Comment: Yes I tried that but these functions are not supported in bootstrap 5

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `hide()` does not toggle the element correctly for some reason as it changes the style for all popover elements (both old and new). After experimenting and searching online, I get it to work by using `popover('hide')` instead of `hide()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'));
        var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
          return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".popover .close-popover" , function(event){
          $(this).closest(".popover").popover('hide');
        });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn  btn-primary ripple-effect m-4" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-content="<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='d-flex justify-content-end close-popover' aria-label='Close'><div class='icon icon-16 icon-lg-16 mb-2'>X</div></a><div  class='sec-paragraph'><div class='p4'><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur apising elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</p></div> </div>">Popover(White) left with close btn</a>
```